# Usefulness of the varying methods of dictionary declaration in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the Python spec they define dictionaries in a variety of ways:

```
a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
```

Is there a useful distinction in how the assignment is made in the cases where we use zip vs. dict() on a list in the following case?

```
c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
```

I could guess at using zip: to assign values from one list to its corresponding index in another, but the following case below is a bit more arcane.

Further, is there a useful distinction in calling `dict()`explicitly on the `{}` enclosure rather than allowing python to implicitly assign `b` to a dict vs. `e`?

```
e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

To make my question clear:

Are there corner cases where these varying methods are more useful? Why use zip over a flat dict call; and why would we use dict() when we already tell python to identify a dict with `{}`?

Comment: *e* is good for shallow copies, *d* for converting for example an SQL result set to dict, *c* when you have a separate header sequence and value sequences.

Comment: This one: `dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})` makes zero-sense. Just use `{'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}`. Indeed, all your examples above don't make sense unless the arguments/constructions aren't being hard-coded. Note, dictionary literals are the *fastest*, but that usually shouldn't matter. IOW, these are more or less useful depending on what you are dealing with to start with.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I wonder why someone would use `e` instead of `dict.copy`: `e = {1: 2}.copy()`